# Making more of Perl Data::Dumper output

Tags: perl, data-dumper, data-dump

I have several nested data structures that refer to one another's elements. I would like to be able to check those references, so I am searching for something that will print the memory address of nested structures. An option for `Data::Dumper` would be fine.

Here are some examples of what I mean:

```
my @a = ( [1,2,3], [4,5,6] );
print \@a;
```

Will give you something like:

```
ARRAY(0x20071dc8)
```

When you run the same code through the debugger and examine the array with `x \@a` it will print this:

```
0  ARRAY(0x20070668)
   0  ARRAY(0x2006c0d8)
      0  1
      1  2
      2  3
   1  ARRAY(0x2006c1b0)
      0  4
      1  5
      2  6
```

But using `Data::Dumper`

```
print Dumper \@a;
```

It looks like this

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ],
          [
            4,
            5,
            6
          ]
        ];
```

What I really want is a mixture of the `Data::Dumper` output and the details that the debugger provides. Perhaps this

```
$VAR1 = [ ARRAY(0x20070668)
          [ ARRAY(0x2006c0d8)
            1,
            2,
            3
          ],
          [ ARRAY(0x2006c1b0)
            4,
            5,
            6
          ]
        ];
```

---

**Edit**

Consider this code. The output doesn't explain that `$b[1]` is the same reference as in `$a[0]`

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @a = ( [1,2,3], [4,5,6] );
my @b = ( ["a","b","c"], $a[0] );

print Dumper \@b

print $b[1], "\n";
print $a[0], "\n";
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'a',
            'b',
            'c'
          ],
          [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ]
        ];


ARRAY(0x2002bcc0)
ARRAY(0x2002bcc0)
```

Also, is this approach, when one structure references the contents of another, considered to be good programming practice? Maybe this is too general question and heavily depends on particular code but I would like to know your opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) will already tell if a reference is reused.

In the following example, the 2nd and 3rd elements of the AoA are identical.  This is represented in the Dumper output:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = (1..3);
my @array2 = (4..6);

my @AoA = (\@array1, \@array2, \@array2);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@AoA;
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ],
          [
            4,
            5,
            6
          ],
          $VAR1->[1]
        ];
```

---

#### Responding to your edit

If you want to find the relation between two different data structures, just make a single call to Dumper with both data structures.

You can do this by passing them as a list, or as values in another anonymous data structure, like a hash or array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6]);
my @b = (["a","b","c"], $a[0]);

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper(\@a, \@b);
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            1,
            2,
            3
          ],
          [
            4,
            5,
            6
          ]
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          [
            'a',
            'b',
            'c'
          ],
          $VAR1->[0]
        ];
```

Comment: Yes but when you have cross references between another nested structures it tells nothing about it.

Comment: `Dumper($var1, $var2)` would actually suffice

Comment: You might find `$Data::Dumper::Purity = 1;` useful.

Comment: Yes, both of those tips are useful.  The latter reminds me that this is yet another reason why I prefer [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump), since it does Purity by default.

Comment: Data::Dumper's defaults are awful :( Useqq, Sortkeys, Purity should all be `1`.

Comment: @Miller: `Data::Dump` also answers this question quite neatly.

Comment: @Borodin: Nice Solution.  Yeah, I definitely like to promote `Data::Dump` as well, but I will try to balance that with letting the OP specify some preference as well.  Your solution does a nice job answering the OP's specific question.   Gotta say though, the goal of listing the Array references feels like an XY Problem to me, and that a more readable format is letting `Data::Dumper` or `Data::Dump` show the relation between data structures by simply dumping them together.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that far too little attention is paid to [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump). It is written by Gisle Aas, the author of the remarkable `LWP` suite of modules.

It will help you in this case because there is a companion [`Data::Dump::Filtered`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump::Filtered) module that allows you to supply a callback to dictate exactly how each item should be displayed in the dump.

This program takes the data in your question as an example. It employs a callback that adds the stringified version of the reference as a Perl comment before each array is displayed. The dump is very similar to your requirement, and as a bonus it is still valid Perl code that can be passed through `eval` if necessary.

Note that all dump output is sent to `STDERR` so I have called `select STDERR` to keep the `print` output in synch with the dumps.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump::Filtered qw/ dump_filtered /;

my @a = ( [1,2,3], [4,5,6] );
my @b = ( [ qw/ a b c / ], $a[0] );

select STDERR;

dump_filtered(\@a, \&filter);
print "\n";

dump_filtered(\@b, \&filter);
print "\n";

print '$b[1] is ', $b[1], "\n";
print '$a[0] is ', $a[0], "\n";

sub filter {
  my ($thing, $ref) = @_;
  return { comment => "$ref" } if $thing->is_array;
}
```

**output**

```
# ARRAY(0x45179c)
[
  # ARRAY(0xa2d36c)
  [1, 2, 3],
  # ARRAY(0x44adc4)
  [4, 5, 6],
]

# ARRAY(0x4e6964)
[
  # ARRAY(0xa2d534)
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  # ARRAY(0xa2d36c)
  [1, 2, 3],
]

$b[1] is ARRAY(0xa2d36c)
$a[0] is ARRAY(0xa2d36c)
```